# Set value of a property where the property name is dynamic, AND contains a '.'

Tags: javascript

I have some code which works with a set of data which has come from the server.

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, Opened: false, Message: {
        { Subject: 'A message', Body: '....', Date: '2015-06-21T17:35:15' },
    },
    { Id: 2, Opened: true, Message: {
        { Subject: 'A message', Body: '....', Date: '2015-05-21T17:35:15' },
    }
];
```

I don't know that the date is going to be under the property `Message.Date`, as it depends on what the server returns. However, I will always have a list of the fields for data item. Using this example, I'll have something like this:

```
var fields = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Field', type: 'varchar'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Opened', type: 'bool'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Message.Subject', type: 'varchar'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Message.Body', type: 'varchar'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Message.Date', type: 'date'},
];
```

I want to transform the Date property to be a Date object.

Assuming that `fields` and `data` have come from the result of an AJAX call, then my code looks something like this...:

```
$.each(response.fields, function(idx,field){
    var dataItems = response.data;
    $.each(dataItems, function(rowIdx, rowItem){
        if(field.type == 'date'){
            dataItems[rowIdx][field.name] = new Date(dataItems[rowIdx][field.name]);
        }
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, because I end up trying to access the property named 'Message.Date' of the object, rather than the 'Date' property of the 'Message' property of the object.

I've been doing something like this to handle it so far:

```
var date = dataItems[rowIdx];
var fieldPropertyLabelSplit = field.propertyLabel.split('.');
for (var i = 0; i < fieldPropertyLabelSplit.length; ++i) {
    date = date[fieldPropertyLabelSplit[i]];
}
dataItems[rIdx][field.propertyLabel] = new Date(date);
```

This way, `new Date(date)` is OK, but I end up with A instead of B...:

```
A:                                         B:
 { Message.Date: _date_ };                  { Message: { Date: _date _ }};
```

The only way I've found to get this to work as I'd like is by using `eval`...

```
var pN = 'dataItems[rIdx]';
for (var i = 0; i < fieldPropertyLabelSplit.length; ++i) {
    pN += '["' + fieldPropertyLabelSplit[i] + '"]';
}
eval(pN +'= new Date(date);');
```

Are there any libraries or simple functionality I've missed which can handle this sort of use-case? Is this appropriate use of eval? Unfortunately, I have no control server-side, and I end up passing this result to a third-party component which I can't change either.

Comment: @nnnnnn This results in: `{ "property.name.with.dots": "some value"; }` See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/hqxs73ry/).

Comment: Yes, that's why I deleted the comment immediately after making it. I got confused by the subject line of your question, which seemed to be asking for that. Might be helpful if you updated that fiddle to include the data from the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace you iterating solution with:

```
var date = dataItems[rowIdx];
var fieldPropertyLabelSplit = field.propertyLabel.split('.');
for (var i = 0; i < fieldPropertyLabelSplit.length - 1; ++i) {
    date = date[fieldPropertyLabelSplit[i]];
}
date[fieldPropertyLabelSplit[i]] = new Date(date[fieldPropertyLabelSplit[i]]);
```

That way, `date` points to the last object before the actual value, and `i` is the index in the array of the last name. When you set the value like this, you maintain your object structure.

Comment: Thanks Amit. It's only a small optimization, but I'll take it :). I was hoping for something which removes a lot of the work, but I can just wrap it up myself. Thanks.

Comment: I thought you wanted to avoid the "evil `eval`" ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's a part of it too. Having one of those days! My apologies.